# Is it possible to mine on testnet using --light option?

Tags: testnets, light-clients

Iw ould like to get some testnet eth on my wallet, but don't want to download the testnet but start geth with --light. Would that be possible?

Comment: You can download the chrome extension Metamask, generate an account and use the Metamask faucet https://faucet.metamask.io to get free testnet ether. That will be easier than mining.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way I found is going to:

http://faucet.ropsten.be:3001/donate/"your-eth-address"